# Reopen: "optional internal interview" (REOPENED)

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

My question was marked as off topic because it asked for advice. I'm new to this network so happy to try and make it on topic! I've made a decent edit (revision 2) to the question's phrasing, and would appreciate re-open votes so I can gain answers.

If this question is still off topic, does it seem like a question which will never be appropriate or which just needs to be properly framed? If it's the former I'll just delete it and save my curiosity for another time!

Question: [Optional internal interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92033/optional-internal-interview)

Comment: Good edit.  It has been reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been reopened.

I have made further minor edits to the post, and expanded the title to a question.

Comment: Thanks, that title is a good improvement

Comment: @workharder You are welcome. This is how things usually work over here on The Workplace. We put a question in less than ideal form on hold, then someone edits it and/or makes a meta post, and we reopen it. :) Sometimes, we also have close/reopen tennis matches when people don't agree that the edits are a substantial improvement, but I think that won't happen with this question.